# Can I display university logos on my website under "Used by students and faculty from"

Tags: united-states, internet, trademark, australia, branding

I have a website mostly used by students and university faculty, and I'd like to display those universities' logos on my website.

Examples are: Yale, NYU, UCONN, University of Dallas, University of Sydney, Texas University, Hawaii University, etc

Can I do that? I'm not sure. Maybe I have to contact all of them get individual approval.

[Yale's guidelines](https://yaleidentity.yale.edu/yale-logo-wordmarks) talk about publications - but my website is not a publication. ("Only with the approval of the Director of Marketing and Trademark Licensing may the Yale logo or wordmarks be used in non-Yale publications or event displays.")

[This Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-a-colleges-logo-on-my-website-without-violating-trademark-law) suggests it varies case-to-case - hence this question.

[This Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/legaladvice/comments/7ck04o/comment/dpqhm6n/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) suggests that, in order for it to be *not* okay, the user of logo has to also do it "without the consent of the plaintiff (*university*) in a manner that is likely to cause confusion among ordinary consumers as to the source, sponsorship, affiliation, or approval of the goods."

The answer to [an older question of mine](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31069/can-i-use-brand-logos-on-a-website-template-im-going-to-be-selling) here on Law suggests I'm in the clear.

Thank you

Comment: Why on Earth do you think your website is not a publication? It most definitely is.

Comment: @Nij that’s a question i linked in my question. Answer: not exactly.

Comment: @Dale ah okay. If you want to post it as an answer so I can accept, feel free, it answers my question. Thank you

Comment: You've now accepted an answer that tells you it was also covered by the duplicate already. That's pretty strong sign that you didn't read the answer and should seek clarification, not ask a different question.

Comment: @Nij You could definitely say that. I'm completely out of my territory in Law, so I was really trying to ask a specific, narrow question. The other question doesn't completely address this use case, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer to that older question of yours, criterion (2) is probably violated by your plan:

> only so much of the mark as is reasonably necessary to identify the product or service is used

You could just as easily (in fact, more easily) identify the schools by writing their names in plain text rather than using their wordmarks or logos.  According to [this article from the Dallas Bar Association](https://www.gibsondunn.com/wp-content/uploads/documents/publications/Davies-Tobin-Fair-Use-Implications-of-Using-the-Logos-of-Others-%20-Dallas-Bar-Association-2-2017.pdf), some courts have found use of logos excessive when just the words would do:

> Other courts declined to apply fair use for a tourist map using a stylized form of "DISNEYLAND" accompanied by the castle logo, or for a collector's guide using the "TY" Heart logo along with bold lettering.

The above linked article notes at the end that "application of the fair use doctrine is a fact-intensive inquiry", which is a fancy way of saying "fair use depends on the situation and lawyers get paid lots of money to argue about it."

Finally, the above article also provides some practical guidelines that are worth considering as well.  These include:

> - Circumventing the issue by obtaining permission from the IP owner to use its logo
> - Avoiding logos or distinctive lettering, if words are sufficient to identify the products of others;
> - Including additional description and referential phrases (e.g. "runs on" or "compatible with"), rather than a bare listing of logos;
> - Including a conspicuous disclaimer of endorsement, sponsorship, and affiliation that is at least as large as the logos

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that’s valuable knowledge. I will contact them. Unfortunately, I do have to use the logos-words won’t  suffice because of the lost visual appeal (in UI context).

Comment: @The Onin  No  you do not **have to** use the graphic logos when you could use the names, perhaps each on a bit of background to make it stand out. It might be more effective design to use the logos, but using he names would sufficiently identify the various universities. Or you could use the names along with links to the universities' own web sites, where a logo would no doubt be displayed.