# Are old school logos under copyright?

Tags: copyright, australia

I wanted to use a school logo on my website. This is an [example of one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_Grammar_School#/media/File:Sydney_Grammar_School_Logo.png) (which is a private school) and [here is another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:North_Sydney_Girls_High_logo.jpg) (a public school).

Wikipedia says that they are both no longer in copyright. But when on the government [website](https://education.nsw.gov.au/about-us/copyright), it says this about the copyright:

> Material on this website not available under a Creative Commons
> licence includes:
>
> - the Department of Education logo, other logos and trademark-protected material

Is this statement the Department of Education made true? It seems to me that the copyright has indeed expired. Is the Department of Education just making a blanket statement that may not be true if the logo is very old?

Comment: A heraldic subtelty might come into play here. The [blazon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazon) (i.e. written description) is typically fixed, and will go out of copyright in due time (arguably, it is even non-copyrightable if simple enough). However, the specific artistic depiction might be changed from time to time, and there is copyright in each new instance. Therefore, anyone can create an image of "Azure, a garb Or"; but if you want to reuse the exact image currently used by the current Duke of Westminster, you will need to get agreement from them and/or their artist.

Comment: The Canterbury Tales is also not available under a Creative Commons license, yet the copyright has expired.  In fact, it is only material with copyright that _hasn't_ expired where you need to worry about a license.

Comment: Also, what do you want to use it for?  There are circumstances under which you can use copyright-protected material without a license, and _most_ uses of trademarks do not require a license.

Comment: @phoog it would be used on a commerical website using the logo to show that a student from that school had used our service.

Comment: Don't know what the rule is for Austrilia, but in the U.S. government documents are automatically public domain, so the public schools and government bodies like the school board would have public domain logos .

Answer (score 4):

I can see two points you might be confused about in your question.

#### 1. Works can be in the public domain without having a CC license

The Wikipedia statement and the government statement are not inconsistent with each other;  just because something isn't available under a Creative Commons license doesn't necessarily mean that it is restricted by copyright.  In fact, [CC licenses are moot for material in the public domain:](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/public_domain)

> When a work is in the public domain, it is free for use by anyone for any purpose without restriction under copyright law. Public domain is the purest form of open/free, since no one owns or controls the material in any way. ... Creative Commons licenses do not affect the status of a work that is in the public domain under applicable law, because our licenses only apply to works that are protected by copyright.

So if a work is in the public domain, you can use it for whatever purpose you wish (though see below), without restriction or attribution.  This is less restrictive than the various Creative Commons licenses, which require various levels of attribution, non-modification, etc. depending on the license chosen by the creator.

#### 2. Trademark protections are separate from copyright protections

Your quote from the government website implies that these logos might be trademarked, even if they're not under copyright;  this is entirely possible.  Roughly speaking, trademark protections keep other people from trading on your good name & reputation; copyright protections keep other people from directly profiting from your creative endeavors.

If another party creates a product that uses a trademark in a way that would create confusion among consumers, the trademark holder can sue for that.  Depending on how you use the logos, you might run afoul of these protections.  See [this Q&A for futher details under US law.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74218/) (Australian law may differ a bit but I would expect that the general principles are the same.)

Comment: Some of them are trademarked - some are not. For a trademarked logo - if I use the logo in a way that only suggests that a student from that school has used my service (placing the logo alongside other school logos) - would that be infringing trademark?

Comment: This is the link to their trademark: https://search.ipaustralia.gov.au/trademarks/search/view/1012546?q=sydney+grammar

Comment: So if the school hasn't registered for trademark protection in regards to tutoring services, would I be able to use them? It seems they only registered for clothing.

Comment: @JohnHon:  For your first question, see the link above near the end of my answer.  For your second question, I have no idea.  In any event, I would suggest you consult a real lawyer instead of random folks on the internet like me.  :-)

Comment: "I would suggest you consult a real lawyer instead of random folks on the internet" Especially if your use of the trademark is to imply that you have a relationship with them you don't!